# SoftEther VPN Client IP Routing on Linux

Tags: linux, iptables, ip, routing, vpn

I'm having some problems to establish routing tables on my linux client machine using a Site-to-Site(LAN-to-LAN) VPN (softether). It works great for Windows clients , but for linux I don't know how to route the traffic to the server.
This image shows my current configuration:
[image: vpn]

I'm stuck in the "ip route add ..." step. The vpn is connected and I have an IP address coming from the Site A router (after running "dhclient vpn_vpn0") which is "192.168.0.105" but I'm unable to ping to "192.168.0.97" and of course I can't access to the machines in there. DHCP is enabled .

How is the way to route the traffic so I can ping to the Site A hosts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To help people figure out your setup, you should give your current network setup (once your VPN is running): `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route; ip rule`. You can [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/572069/edit) your question to add these informations.